# How to add Redux DevTools Extension to my react-redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to add the Redux DevTools Chrome extension to my redux store and described here: http://extension.remotedev.io/

Here's my store:

```
let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {

  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer(),
      cats: catReducer
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate()
    ),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

The extension in Chrome is still showing:

> No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This video explains how to connect devtool to the app - https://youtu.be/TSOVLXQPWgA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The devtools needs to be within your compose.

Try:

```
let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {

  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer(),
      cats: catReducer
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate(),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In compose, you need to return the arguments when the extension is not available:

```js
compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    : args => args,
),
```