# How to run Redux DevTools Extension INSIDE Chrome Extension running React?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

The big issue i'm facing is I'm seeing the error `"No store found"` when trying to access my redux store in the [Redux DevTools Extension](http://extension.remotedev.io/) WHILE my React app is running inside a Chrome Extension.

I've seen a few questions on SO about similar errors, like:

1. [“No store found” when using Redux chrome extension"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526621/no-store-found-when-using-redux-chrome-extension)
2. ["How to add Redux DevTools Extension to my react-redux store?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164058/how-to-add-redux-devtools-extension-to-my-react-redux-store)

Most of the answers to these questions relate to specifying the correct variables like using `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` instead of `devToolsExtension` (after the extension was upgraded), or installing the `npm` package `redux-devtools-extension`.

My problem is different - if I run my a React app (in development mode), outside of the Chrome Extension (a.k.a. not through the Chrome Extension's `options` page), I find that the Redux DevTools Extension works fine for me. However, as I mentioned before, when I run the React app from within the Chrome Extension `options` page, the Redux DevTools Extension cannot find the store.

Here is my `index.js` file that I use inside the `options` page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './App';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/root';

// 
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    : null
        || compose;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I believe the error has to do with the fact that that I'm running the React App from within the `options` page of my Chrome Extension. I've found that `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` is `undefined` from the Chrome Extension `options` page, but that `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` variable is visible and accessible on normal pages. Is there any tried and tested way of making `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` available in the `options` page of a Chrome Extension?

Comment: Extensions can't run their scripts inside another extension's page context which is why Redux extension is unable to define a property on `window`.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh bummer... I guess that makes sense... So do you think a possible workaround would be for the extensions to pass messages back and forth? I've seen this in the chrome extension docs but haven't used it. Also it's probably not actually supported in the `Redux DevTools Extension`, but it could theoretically work that way, right??

Comment: Yeah, cross-extension messaging could work if both extensions support it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Remote Redux Devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools) in this case.

Add this to your store creation (`yarn add --dev  remote-redux-devtools`):

```
import devToolsEnhancer from "remote-redux-devtools";

const store = createStore(
  popupReducer,
  devToolsEnhancer({
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 8000,
    realtime: true
  }) 
);
```

You will also need a remotedev server, I went with a local one:

```
yarn add --dev remotedev-server
cd /node_modules/.bin/
remotedev --port=8000
```

Now you can connect and monitor your store using the [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd), click the Remote button, go to settings and click "Use custom (local) server" there and you should see your store in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I made it by installing `"@redux-devtools/cli"` and `"@redux-devtools/remote"` packages. Then opening external redux devtools instance and devserver with `redux-devtools --hostname=localhost --port=8000 --open`. Then injecting the enhancer with:

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import testStore from "./testStore";
import {devToolsEnhancer} from "@redux-devtools/remote";

const store = configureStore({
        reducer: testStore.reducer,
        enhancers: [devToolsEnhancer({
            name: "Redux", hostname: "localhost", port: 8000
        })]
    });
```

For some reason, I couldn't connect from the Redux Devtools extension for popup/newtab pages. Only external instance worked for me.

Comment: Can you provide the code of `testStore` and the code you use `Provide={store}`? I did the same thing with you but I always see empty... https://i.imgur.com/nJFolji.png. The devTools definitely connects to 8000 devServer, and I set up enahcner as above... but still does not work. So frustratting..